# Get the columns length of a data.frame

Tags: r

I have a data.frame composed by N columns. The columns have not the same length (i.e. complete.cases), e.g. Column1: 314 rows, Column2: 543 rows, Column3: 124 rows, ...
I would like to retrieve the length for each Column for the entire data.frame. 
Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Columns can't have different lengths within the same `data.frame` by definition, please clarify your question or this will be closed soon.

Comment: What does `str(...)` give you when you run it with your data? I tried with a fabricated `data.frame` and it displayed the length of all objects (or the length of the `data.frame` as the columns are of similar length). Not really sure though how it fares in a situation where the column lengths differ.

Comment: Try `sapply(df, function(x) sum(complete.cases(x)))` (if your dataset called `df`).

Comment: To pile on, please amend your question with more information. Structure of the data.frame is minimal what we need to see, a reproducible example with expected result would be ideal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you want to count the `complete.cases` per column in your data set. Here's an example data set

```
set.seed(123)
(df <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(NA, 1:5), 25, replace = TRUE), ncol = 5)))
#   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
# 1  1 NA  5  5  5
# 2  4  3  2  1  4
# 3  2  5  4 NA  3
# 4  5  3  3  1  5
# 5  5  2 NA  5  3
```

And here's a possible solution

```
sapply(df, function(x) sum(complete.cases(x)))
# V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 
#  5  4  4  4  5
```

Or you could vectorize this using `colSums` and `!is.na`

```
colSums(!is.na(df))
# V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 
#  5  4  4  4  5
```